# Modules are not showing in the list of modules

Tags: installation

When I add new modules in the production website, they don't shown up the list of modules. So, I took a copy, and changed the values in the database, the content of the settings.php file, and the modules are listed in the local machine.

Before this post, I took some debugging measures, which are:

- I checked that sites/all/modules has the file permissions 755
- I checked the module version is correct
- I cleared the cache table

Comment: Which Drupal version? Paste code of your .info file here.

Comment: I have a development local site with the same type of problem, the core modules show, but the contributed ones do not.  I have not been able to solve the problem, but being a sandbox site, I just recreated it. Can you see any contributed modules?  In my case the bad site was created by installing the core using quickstart module and then copied the modules over from another site, imported the database by using phpmyadimin, and ran update.php.  Have you checked your settings.php file?

Comment: This question may be related: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28678

Comment: check 755 permission for sites/all/module INCLUDING subfolders and 644 permission for files recursively

Comment: Nikhil its drupal 6.19 and name = Panels
description = Core Panels display functions; provides no external UI, at least one other Panels module should be enabled.
core = 6.x
package = "Panels"
dependencies[] = ctools

; Information added by drupal.org packaging script on 2012-01-18
version = "6.x-3.10"
core = "6.x"
project = "panels"
datestamp = "1326917148"

Comment: Hi its solved. Thanks for all your support. its related to ownership issues